# Image Editing on Web Application

Tags: javascript, html, api, image-processing, canvas

On my website users have some images stored. I want to build a system where they can edit those images on website and save them. Edits are very basic like rotate, crop, enhance brightness add filters etc. **I'm trying to figure out how I can implement this**.

My understanding so far is that there are multiple ways in which I can do this. I can write all my image editing code(using libraries) on server side and then call this service API from my website.

I can also make all the changes on client side. I found PicMonkey library which would let me do it (it's flash based though so I don't really want to use it.)

I also checked how flickr does it, they use this library https://developers.aviary.com/ which lets them do all the client side edits.

I'd like to know more about using these client side javascript libraries ( such as aviary ) what are the pros and cons of using them vs server side edits. What service component I need to write, if at all if I'm using something like Avairy. More specifically, do I send image to server for modification or do I modify it on HTML canvas first and then send the modified image to server to save it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today browsers have become very strong, so you should probably do the basic edits on the client side itself, so there is not too much burden on your server and also utilize the processing power of the client.

You have few libraries for doing this on the client side

1) https://developers.aviary.com/

2) http://camanjs.com/

3) http://www.pixastic.com/editor-test/

but as you say,

> Edits are very basic like rotate, crop, enhance brightness add
>   filters etc

You can create your own code for these kind of edits, there are lot of tutorials out there, few I found useful are here,

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-grayscale-image-colors-tutorial/

http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/

there are few things which if you try to do on the client side they will crash your app completely, for ex. a photo bucket tool.
Here is a tutorial as well for creating a photo bucket tool which uses a flood fill algorithm.

http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/
But you should keep these kind of heavy algorithms on your server so your app doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are good in server side programming my spontaneuos thought was "Why not using the raw PHP GD library or the PHP add-on imagemagick?"

http://www.imagemagick.org/

[Photo editing in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704651/photo-editing-in-php)

It depends on what server load you are expecting - up to 10 people simultaneously working on it would be OK, but 100 to 1000 people at once?  For the second case a client side editing is really the better option, or your server will overload.  Naeem-Shaikh gave you some links for that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommed to make it client side.

JavaScript will give you everything you need for basic editing and you ll be able to organize your code in a clean way.
A client side app won t force you to deal with XHR, wait, send, http, all of those you have to master for the same server side app to always display the current draft. Server side you will need servers with available ressources to do the job.

User will be able to continue editing even if they lost connection, and trust me this alone should be enough of a pro to do it client side. Also the editing will feel more fluid.

So why would even hesitate ? Well, server side also has advantages.
There are many (10+) librairies tested, documented, enhanced ready to be used. Perhaps you don t have time or energy to learn JavaScript. Maybe in the future, you ll want to expand your app with new, heavy, editing features that takes more CPU than client have, ...

Comment: okay but you don't say how client side?

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=image+editor&type=Repositories
Do some research, or ask a more specific question

Comment: So its css providing the exact pixel access? I've found a way that roughly opens/creates .bmp but it requires awareness of .bmp encoding.